# How to overlay a single FloatingActionButton over a TopTabbedPage

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, floating-action-button, tabbedpage

I am having a `NavigationPage` containing a `TopTabbedPage` which is implemented with `Naxam.TopTabbedPage.Forms`

```
<forms:TopTabbedPage ...>
    <views:ContentPage1 ...>
    <views:ContentPage2 ...>
<forms:TopTappedPage>
```

In the app I want to implement a `FloatingActionButton`, which is the same and shown on both `ContentPage`s. It is easy to implement one on each `ContentPage`, but then the button is also swiped out and replaced by a new one when switching between the two content pages.

The `TopTabbedPage` allows only other pages as content, so i cannot layout something with `StackLayout`, `AbsolutLayout`...

Has someone an idea how i can do this?

Comment: I think using the TabbedPage approach it is not possible!

Comment: do you have an other idea to get something similar with an FAB?

Comment: You could try to search some the third-party tabview control to instead of tabbedpage,then you could use AbsolutLayout to achieve FAB or use FAB directly in MainActivity.

Comment: ok, i'm using now xam.plugin.tabview its functional so far; => thank you